# Redux reducer not changing the store's state properly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am building a small application for adopting pets that has a form to add and delete pets from the adoption list.

API

```
[
   {category: 'dog', pets: [{breed: 'chihuahua', name: 'bar' }, ....]},
   {category: 'cat', pets: [{breed: 'tobby', name: 'foo'}, ....]},
   ....
]
```

Function that creates the form

```
export default function petFieldset({
 petGroups, addPet, deletePet, deleteCategory,
 nameInputChange, breedInputChange, categoryInputChange
}) {

const categoryField = Object.keys(petGroups).map((keys) => (
    <Fieldset
        title={'Pet Category'}
        button={<Delete onClick={deleteCategory.bind(this, { keys })} />}
        key={keys}
    >
        <CategoryComponent
            petGroup={petGroups[keys]}
            deletePet={deletePet}
            categoryKey={keys}
            nameInputChange={nameInputChange}
            breedInputChange={breedInputChange}
            categoryInputChange={categoryInputChange}
        />
        <br />
        <AddPet onClick={addPet.bind(this, { keys })} />
    </Fieldset>
));

return (<div>{ categoryField }</div>);
}
```

My reducer addPet looks like this

```
[ADD_PET]: (state, { payload }) => {
    state[payload.keys].pets.push({ breed: '', name '' });
    return { ...state };
},
```

The *AddPet* component is a button that dispatches the action `ADD_PET` that creates a new form field with the inputs `name` and `breed` at the bottom of the form. This is done by pushing an empty `{ breed: '', name: '' }` to the pets array for the selected category.

The problem is when I try to add a pet more than once.

When a pet is added the first time, it creates an empty form with the `breed` and `name` with empty fields. Now if new pets are added, the form will contain the same `name` and `breed` fields of the field added previously.

example of the unwanted behaviour:

1) form gets loaded with the data from the API as place holder. [expected]

2) user clicks on `AddPet` button which creates a new empty form with `name` and `breed` without placeholders. [expected]

3) user writes the pet name and breed on the newly created form and clicks the `AddPet` component. [expected]

4) a new form with same `name` and `breed` as in step 3). [unexpected]

Something is happening with the `state[payload.keys].faqs.push({ breed: '', name '' })` from the reducer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

push is not an immutable operation. you are changing the array itself. So it has the same state and previous state.

You have to create a copy of previous array, and push into this new copy the new item.

For example:

```
[ADD_PET]: (state, { payload }) => {
    let pets = [...state[payload.keys].pets];
    pets.push({ breed: '', name '' });
    return { ...state, payload.keys: pets };
},
```